# MVC 3 AJAX not working in IPad

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, ipad

I am trying to figure out why my AJAX call to a Web service is working on every browser but the IPad. I have an MVC 3 application which makes a Web Service call using Ajax.Actionlink to a Sharepoint API. The call works great everywhere, but the experience seems to fall short on the IPad. on the IPad, I am getting results similar to if you implemented the Ajax.ActionLink without referencing the jquery and Microsoft js scripts. I have tried enabling the Developer tools on the IPad and no longer get an errors. (The only error i was receiving was i tried using the CDN library Microsoft uses and the IPad didn't like that at all.) Now those errors are gone and the call redirects the page to a Partial view. This should not be happening as every other browser (including Safari for windows) seems to display a loading gif and then load the information within the same page. No redirection. Any ideas?

Site Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <%-- <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="•http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"/>--%>

    </head>

<body style="background-color:White">
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>


            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">              
                    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                   </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index: ( main page)

```
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />


    <%:/* This calls the Ajax namespace to invoke an async call to a controller method
        * we are using the POST method because the GET cache's the callback results
        * Refernce: 
        * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282497/tinymce-in-mvc-3-razor-ajax-actionlinks-fail-after-first-ajax-call */
    Ajax.ActionLink("Click to Get CIMS Folder", "CallWebService", new AjaxOptions()
                                                        {
                                                        UpdateTargetId = "placeHolder",
                                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                        LoadingElementId = "indicator",
                                                        HttpMethod="POST",
                                                        })
        %>
    <div id="indicator">
        <img alt="AJAX Indicator" src="<%= Url.Content("~/images/ajax-loader.gif") %>" />
    </div>
    <div id="placeHolder">
    </div>
```

PartialView (Makecall.ascx)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AsyncCallTest.Models.SharepointModel>" %>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td><font color="Black">Folder Name</font></td>
    <td><font color="Black">Link</font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

    <% if (Model != null)
       {
           for (int fileCounter = 0; fileCounter < Model.FolderList.Count(); fileCounter++ )
           {
               foreach (var file in Model.FolderList[fileCounter].FolderFiles)
               {
           %>
            <td><font color="Black"> <%: file.FileName%></font></td>
            <td><font color="Black"> <a href ='<%: file.FileWebPath%>'><%: file.FileWebPath%></a></font></td>
             </tr>
           <%
               }
           }
       }

         %>

         </table>
```

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is that if you are calling ajax on HTTPS, if the security certificate is not valid iPad might refuse to contact the service. I'd just suggest to test it over iPhone just to test the issue is related to iPad and not someway to iOS network stack

Comment: @ChristianAchilli - Yeah it seems to happen on both. But i have a hard time believing that IPad doesn't support AJAX??

Comment: iPad do support AJAX. I meant that if you are trying to invoke the ajax service over https, you have to be sure the vertificate is a valid one otherwise the connection is refused. Happy you solved that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the CDN's were the issue, so I changed the

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript" /> 
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"/> 
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

to

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now it works. Thank you. Just odd that it worked in everything but IPad Safari and Javascript was enabled, so you would think it would have worked.